# windows azure virtual machine hard disk backups

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When using Virtual Servers on Windows Azure and attaching disks - Would these go down if the hard disk / server should fail?  Or are they guaranteed to be backed up?  Should we still keep an external backup ourselves, or can we depend on Azure?

Also, would the primary hard-disk as part of the server, also follow the same backup principles?  And same applies for blob-storage, would that need to be backed up?

Answer (score 1):

Azure attached disks, just like the OS disk, is stored as a vhd, inside a blob in Azure Storage. This is *durable* storage: triple-replicated within the data center, and optionally geo-replicated to a neighboring data center.

That said: If you delete something, it's instantly deleted. No going back. So... then the question is, how to deal with backups from an app-level perspective. To that end:

- You can make *snapshots* of the blob storing the vhd. A snapshot is basically a linked list of all the pages in use. In the event you make changes, then you start incurring additional storage, as additional page blobs are allocated. The neat thing is: you can take a snapshot, then in the future, copy the snapshot to its own vhd. Basically it's like rolling backups with little space used, in the event you only add data and don't modify.
- You can make blob copies. This is an async action that is near-instant within a single data center. I've seen copies take upwards of an hour going cross-data center. But the point is that you can make copies any time you want, and this will be in its own blob.

Comment: So basically as long as there is no accidental deletions, etc. I can safely rely on the fact that Azure will replicate the data behind the hoods, and it can't go wrong?  Any references on Azure's Terms & Conditions / Policy mentioning this fact?  I am not worried about accidental deletion, it's more about having to keep a copy of the actual data just in case things go wrong and I end up with an empty HD, given that all the implementation details are abstracted out.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer (and I don't work in LCA at Microsoft), so I'll refer you to [this description](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/storage/what-is-a-storage-account/) of storage. I didn't see anything called out in the [ToS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6656). If data is critical, strongly consider making a copy of your vhd blob (or extracting backup data some other way). This way, you have peace of mind...